# How can I use <source_model> for a textbox in Magento for system.xml?

Tags: magento

Because it's for a textbox, I'm not sure how the array is supposed to work.

**This fails.**

```
public function getDefault_dailymatches()
{
    return array(
      array('value' => 0, 'label' => Mage::helper()->__('First item')),
      array('value' => 1, 'label' => Mage::helper()->__('Second item')),
      array('value' => 2, 'label' => Mage::helper()->__('third item')),
     // and so on...
    );    
}
```

**This also fails.**

```
public function getDefault_dailymatches()
{
    $default = 100;
    return $default;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer out myself by searching `Magento.zip` for the evident default textbox variables.

Add this to `config.xml` inbetween the `<config></config>` tags.

```
<default>
    <showdown> <!-- section -->
        <dagroup> <!-- group -->
            <dailymatches>1</dailymatches>
            <maxmatchvotes>100</maxmatchvotes>
            <field>default value</field>
            <!-- <blah><![CDATA[<strong>html tags</strong>]]></blah>
            <blah2><![CDATA[cdata@foremail.addresses]]></blah2> -->
        </dagroup>
    </showdown>        
</default>
```

Comment: This is a bit different of what you initially asked.

Comment: No it isn't. Did you read the question title? _How can I use <source_model> **for a textbox** in Magento for system.xml?_ I wanted to create a default value for a texbox as specified by my question. If `<source_model>` wasn't needed, you should have told me. It's not my fault that Magento doesn't follow `POLS` conventions.